# Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync strips out inline image

Tags: office365, office-addins, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to append text at the end of my email that includes inline image in the body.  I call Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync where I set the coercionType as html. When I send the email the inline image is stripped out.

How can I have the Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync not to strip my inline image?

See example of the API call here: 
https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Body.html

Answer (score 2):

To avoid overwrite the original content, we need to get the body first and then append the content.

Here is an sample for your reference:

```
function appendText() {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html,function (result) {
        var newHtml = result.value.replace("</body>", "<br/ >apend text here.</body>")

        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(newHtml, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  We do this already.  None of the text gets stripped only the inline image.

Comment: The code works well for me. How did you insert the inline image? Did you check the result HTML after your set with the content changed before?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I insert the image by cut and paste to the body of the email. When I call the getASync to get the original HTML (which includes the inline image) and compare with my append HTML there are no changes except for the append HTML. When I use the prependAsync(), the inline image does not get stripped out.  Only when I try to append at the end  of the body and call setAsync the inline image gets stripped out.

Comment: When I say "stripped out", it means in the body of the email the image is shown as broken.  - Thanks

Comment: I am doing this in office add-in

Comment: Kat, can you provide details on the platform you are on? Is this Desktop Outlook or OWA? What version of Desktop Outlook are you using? 

I suspect that this is a bug that has been fixed in Outlook 2016 C2R, but is NOT in Outlook 2016 MSI, or Outlook 2013.